# unable to automate the step of creating replicaset in mongodb through kubernetes deployment file

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have copied install_replicaSet.sh inside the mongo docker image. this script needs to run when all the replica sets have come up.

1. added entrypoint in dockerfile: This is not working.

```
FROM mongo:4.2.6

COPY install_replicaSet.sh /install_replicaSet.sh
RUN chmod +x /install_replicaSet.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash/","/install_replicaSet.sh"]
```

2. added in deployment file: This is also not working.

```
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongo
       # image: mongo
        image: xxxxxxx/mongo:v4.2.6
        command:
        - mongod
        - "--bind_ip_all"
        - "--replSet"
        - rs0
        - ["/bin/bash/", "-c", "/install_replicaSet.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27107
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-volume
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-volume
    spec:
      storageClassName: ebs
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

**install_replicaSet.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cfg="{
    _id: 'rs0',
    members: [
        {_id: 1, host: 'mongo-0.mongo:27017'},
        {_id: 2, host: 'mongo-1.mongo:27017'},
        {_id: 3, host: 'mongo-2.mongo:27017'}
    ]
}"

mongo mongo-0.mongo:27017 --eval "JSON.stringify(db.adminCommand({'replSetInitiate' : $cfg}))"
```

Comment: first off, please explain what is "not working", the script isn't being run? the script is running but not working properly? did you check the logs of the container? and so on.

Comment: I suggest using a mongodb kubernetes operator something like https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/install-k8s-operator/ or https://kubedb.com/docs/v0.13.0-rc.0/guides/mongodb/